# WSO2 CEP: Can I query from rdms table inside siddhi query

Tags: siddhi, wso2-cep

I am trying to learn WSO2 CEP 4.2.0, and I stumble upon some problem with Siddhi query.

Can I getting data from other system rdbms table to use it in event processing ? From WSO2 CEP documentation I found about event table, but that's not what I need.

The scenario is like this:
I use WSO2 CEP to receive tracking data from vehicle. I use that data stream to perform geo-analytical process (geo-fencing, speed limit) and service analytic. For service analytical process I need to lookup to transactional data-table from other system.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain your requirement of accessing the table, so we'll understand as why you cannot use Event Table?

Comment: Hi @Dilini , I have edited my question to show my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: From the given information, it seems like your requirement is achievable by using Event Tables. You can lookup the table by doing a `'join` between an event and the table. Please refer *Join* section in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Eventtable.

Comment: @Dilini , seems like you're right by using 'join'. Could you create an answer with more detail Siddhi QL so I can accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given information, it seems like your requirement is achievable by using Event Tables. You can lookup the table by doing a 'join between an event and the table. Please refer Join section in [Siddhi Query Language guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Eventtable).

For an example on how to use a `JOIN` operation with an Event Table, please refer to [Sample 0106 - Using in-memory event tables](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Sample+0106+-+Using+in-memory+event+tables).

** Although the sample defines an *in-memory* event table as below...

> define table CardUserTable (name string, cardNum string, blacklisted
>   bool) ;

...you can change this definition to make it an RDBMS Event Table by putting the `@From` annotation. E.g.

> @From(eventtable='rdbms', datasource.name='CardTableDatasource',
>   table.name='CardData') define table CardUserTable (name string,
>   cardNum string, blacklisted bool) ;

`@From` annotation elements are being described in [RDBMS event table](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-RDBMSeventtable)
section in the Siddhi documentation.